# Django view/template boxes

Tags: python, django, templates, view

I am new to python/django (came from PHP) and there is a design problem i have no idea how to solve.

Let's say we have main content block and some side column.
Side column displayed at each page of website. But boxes can differ(same set, but in some pages particular boxes disabled)
Side column has several boxes, like news, events, last *anything*, user details, statistics, etc. Dynamic data.

As well as i understand view function should fill context and invoke content.html
(this renders main content block)

While context.html should extend base.html and that base.html has side column inside it.

**The question** is:
How i pass all this data to side boxes(i am reminding, dynamic data connected to some models)? 
I hope someone can explain this to me. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some additional research i found out, that there is 4 ways to do what i want

1) Middleware
2) Context proccessors
3) Inclusion tags(template tags), as Brendon mentioned.
4) django-blocks

I stopped on third approach.
Tested first three.

Decided to start blog, to write down own notes...
More detailed review of this approaches:
http://tigra-potd.blogspot.com/2011/04/django-sidebar-boxesblocksmodules.html

Answer (score 0):

Hi and welcome to Django. The data in the context is available to all blocks. You don't have to do anything specific to pass context data to a block or an include.

Additionally, there are template tags that you can use to encapsulate other functionality that you might need at the template level: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/howto/custom-template-tags/

Comment: Thanks,  but it means, that i have to duplicate everything in every small view. Does not sound DRY :) I am sure i am missing something essential... Probably context['sidebar']=SomeGetterClass.method will do the job. But still must be repeated in every view... Still not nice

Comment: Without seeing exactly what you're trying to accomplish, it's hard to provide an exact solution in code. However, what it *seems* like you'd need/want to do is conditionally include other templates at the top-most level based on their existence in the context. That way you're not repeating anything.

Comment: Hm, thanks for following. I'll try to make it a bit clearly. Lets say i have N dynamic boxes on sidebar. In most of pages displayed all N boxes. So wise decision if every view that provides main content area does not refer to that boxes at all. But sometimes i want to skip several boxes. For example at /videos/ i dont want to display video-related boxes. In this way i'll just add variable into context and template will skip the box. So main question is how actualy PASS data into boxes(base.html-based, not view-based)... Template tags as you mentioned above?

Comment: Yes, with a template tag, you can either pass variables to them from the context, or you can resolve variables from the context server-side. Again, without seeing an exact implementation, I don't know if that's *the* solution for you.